# Next js problem with relative react fuse paths

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fuse

**Hello.** I use **React** **Fuse** in Front End, and **Nextjs** to run the server. But Next has a problem with relative fuse paths, for example the relative path **@history** leads to module not found error !. Is there a way to solve this problem?

```
import history from '@history';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is supported since Next.js 9.5.4. Follow the instruction of the nextjs docs:

> Since Next.js 9.5.4, importing a CSS file from node_modules is permitted anywhere in your application.
>
> For global stylesheets, like bootstrap or nprogress, you should import
> the file inside pages/_app.js. For example:

```
// pages/_app.js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

> For importing CSS required by a third party component, you can do so
> in your component. For example:

```
// components/ExampleDialog.js
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Dialog } from '@reach/dialog'
import '@reach/dialog/styles.css'

function ExampleDialog(props) {
  const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(false)
  const open = () => setShowDialog(true)
  const close = () => setShowDialog(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={open}>Open Dialog</button>
      <Dialog isOpen={showDialog} onDismiss={close}>
        <button className="close-button" onClick={close}>
          <VisuallyHidden>Close</VisuallyHidden>
          <span aria-hidden>×</span>
        </button>
        <p>Hello there. I am a dialog</p>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  )
}
```